# What is reserved space used for in HP MSA 1000 controller

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, raid, raid6

I have configured the HP MSA 1000 by making a RAID level 6 comprising of two pools of 24 TB each. I dont understand why 16 TB is used as the reserved space and what is its purpose? How can i utilise it ?
Below is a snap shot of what i have done so far with the Space. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found a very nice article about the RAID concepts in [this](https://larryjordan.com/articles/partition-a-raid-for-speed/) link.

It explains that the reserved space for RAID-6 is equal to twice the space of one drive which is in my case is 4TB. And since i am making two disk volumes so total space for this is 16 TB. For my later part of the question, it cannot be utilised in any way since its used for data redundancy.